# ASP.NET MVC validation not working when using model casting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My app is basically a survey/test generator, that can output a wide array of question types depending on what is needed. I have a model for each type of question. However, my validation doesn't function (on client side is all I ask, I can do the server-side).

Some of my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<fsForms.Models.abstractQuestion>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
foreach(var item in Model) {
    switch(item.questionType){
    case 1:
        {
            if(item.isRequired)
            {
                var txtReq = (fsForms.Models.FreeTextReq)item;
                @Html.EditorFor(model=> txtReq.textboxVal);
                @Html.ValidatorMessageFor(model=>txtReq.textboxVal);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

My model is simply:

```
public class FreeTextReq:abstractQuestion
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required")]
    public String textboxVal;
}
```

Thanks for any input.

PS: The resulting HTML looks like:

```
<body>
<form action="blahblahblah" method="post">
<input class="text-box single-line" id="txtReq_textboxVal" type="text" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="txtReq.textboxVal" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<input type="submit" value="submit info">
</form>

////////Here follow all my scripts (including jQuery validation scripts) ////////////
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML?

Comment: I edited the question to show output.

Comment: Look the data-valmsg-for="txtReq.textboxVal" and the id="txtReq_textboxVal". They are different, they should match to the validation work. Try to create every fiel without the html helper or force the ID Attribute to be the samer passing htmlAttributes to the helper!

Comment: Good call, but I am very curious as to why they do not match...

Comment: The HTML helper probably is miss understanding the parameter, given that its comming from a variable, not direcly from the model property in the lambda expression!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are set to true in the web.config.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

You also need to include the jquery validation scripts

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```